# Generic parameter T could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I am trying to create a `generic` storage for my app, where `Serializable` items could be stored.

I have some structs that implement `Serializable protocol`

```
 protocol Serializable {
    func serialize() -> [String: AnyObject]
    init?(byDeserializing dictionary : [String: AnyObject])
}
```

This is my `Storage Protocol`

```
protocol Storage {
    func getItems<T:Serializable>(completion : @escaping ([T]?)-> Void )
    func save<T:Serializable>(_ items : [T], completion : @escaping (Bool)-> Void )
}

extension Storage  {

    func data<T:Serializable>(from serializableItems : [T]) -> Data? {

        var serializedItems = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()

        for item in serializableItems {
            serializedItems.append(item.serialize())
        }

        guard let serializedData = try? PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: serializedItems, format:.binary, options:0) else {
            return nil;
        }
        return serializedData

    }

     func serializedItems(from data : Data) -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]? {

        guard  let serilizedItems = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainers, format: nil) as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] else {
            return nil
        }
        return serilizedItems
    }

    func deserialize<T:Serializable>(from serializedItems: [[String : AnyObject]]  ) -> [T] {
        var items = [T]()
        for serializedItem in serializedItems {
            if let item = T(byDeserializing:serializedItem){
                items.append(item)
            }
        }
        return items
    }
}
```

When the app wants to recover stored items it just has to call `self.storage.getItems`....

```
func getItems<T : Serializable>(completion: @escaping ([T]?) -> Void) {
        let path = fileURL().path

        concurrentQueue.async {
            guard let serializedItems = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String : AnyObject]], serializedItems.count > 0 else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            let deserializedItems = self.deserialize(from: serializedItems)
            completion(deserializedItems)
        }
    }
```

I call `getItems` method and I get this compiling error in both storage coordinators

```
PlistStorageCoordinator
```

[image: Generic Error]

```
UserDefaultrsStorageCoordinator
```

[image: Generic inferred error]
It worked perfectly until I add generics to this method. Does any one know what can be wrong?

**I don't know why but this fix it. I don't like it because I am duplicating code in both storages. Some one can explain it to me?**

```
 func getItems<T : Serializable>(completion: @escaping ([T]?) -> Void) {

        concurrentQueue.async {
            guard  let data = self.userDefaults.data(forKey: self.modelKey), let serializedItems = self.serializedItems(from: data), serializedItems.count > 0 else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            var items = [T]()
            for serializedItem in serializedItems {
                if let item = T(byDeserializing:serializedItem){
                    items.append(item)
                }
            }
            completion(items)
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you define `self.storage`. From the error I am thinking it is not in a format where it objects confirms to `Serializable` protocol.

Comment: Try adding the type information to elements, like: `self.storage.getIems { (elements:[CarouselPoi]) in`

Comment: it does not work..  `Cannot convert value of type `([CarouselPoi]) -> ()` to expected argument type `([_]?) -> Void`

Answer (score 4):

This protocol doesn't do what you think it does:

```
protocol Serializable {
    func serialize() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    static func deserialize<T>(_ dictionary : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) -> T
}
```

This says that a Serializable can be serialized to a dictionary, and that any Serializable type has a static method that will convert a dictionary into **something** (T). That "something" has no promises around it. It has nothing to do with the Serializable type. The compiler has no way to guess this type except by seeing what you requested the return value to be.

What you meant almost certainly is that a Serializable can be deserialized from a dictionary:

```
protocol Serializable {
    func serialize() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    static func deserialize(_ dictionary : [String: AnyObject]) -> Self
}
```

This says what you mean, but it's almost impossible to implement in a way that won't crash. What if the dictionary doesn't include keys you expect? What do you return then? This method should be either optional or throwing, and it would be much Swiftier as a init. For example:

```
protocol Serializable {
    func serialize() -> [String: AnyObject]
    init?(byDeserializing dictionary: [String: AnyObject])
}
```

With that, more of your system will work out as you expect.

(All that said, be sure to look at `NSCoding`, which already does what you're trying to do in a more powerful way. There are reasons not to use `NSCoding`, but make sure it's an active choice rather than just reinventing it.)

---

This protocol also does not say what you seem to mean it to say:

```
protocol Storage {
    func getItems<T:Serializable>(completion : @escaping ([T]?)-> Void )
    func save<T:Serializable>(_ items : [T], completion : @escaping (Bool)-> Void )
}
```

This says that a `Storage` can return a list of items of any serializable type, and can save a list of item of any serializable type. Those types don't have to be related in any way. What you seem to mean is that a Storage can get and save items of a *particular* type, associated with that Storage. In that case you want an associated type:

```
protocol Storage {
    associatedType Element
    func getItems(completion : @escaping ([Element]?)-> Void )
    func save(_ items : [Element], completion : @escaping (Bool)-> Void )
}
```

This function:

```
func getItems<T:Serializable>(completion : @escaping ([T]?)-> Void )
```

takes two parameters. The second parameter you probably understand. It's `completion`, and it's a function that takes an optional array and returns Void. But I believe you're misunderstand the first parameter: `T`. When you call `getItems` you are implicitly passing a *type* as one of the parameters. Every time you call `getItems`, you can pass a different `T` (just like you can pass a different `completion`. There is nothing about `T` that ties it to this Storable. That's how generics work. What you want is a type that *is* tied to the Storable, and is consistent across all the methods in the Storable. That's an associated type.

Comment: I have tried your approach, but  I get the same issues.. I have edited the my question

Comment: You have the same problem in deserialize and in getItems. You keep injecting a T parameter that you don't give the compiler any way to constrain. What do you expect T to be in the line that your getting the error on?

Comment: In the StorageCoordinators I still want  T elements, It is  in the class where I call the StorageCoordinators where I need the real object. I am sorry but I don't understand generics really well. I've tried to add `as` in the guard let where I get the Items after getItems call, but it does not work